# Is it possible to automount local SMB/CIFS share from /etc/fstab?

Tags: 16.04, mount, samba, fstab, cifs

I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS server with configured public share on it.
My */etc/samba/smb.conf* is below

```
[public_share]
    comment = Ubuntu Public Share
    path = /srv/samba/public_share
    guest ok = yes
    read only = no
```

For some reasons I need to mount this share on boot to */media/public_share*. So I added it to the */etc/fstab*:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
//localhost/public_share /media/public_share/ cifs guest,noperm 0 2
```

But it does not get mounted on boot. It mounts only manually with `sudo mount -a` after login.

Adding it to */etc/rc.local* such as

```
mount -t cifs //localhost/public_share /media/public_share/ -o guest,noperm
```

does not help too.

What am I doing wrong?
How I can auto-mount *//localhost/public_share* to */media/public_share/* during boot?
Do I need special systemd configuration or something special?

**Update 1:**
For *localhost* server name I have the following log:

```
$ systemctl status media-public_share.mount 
● media-public_share.mount - /media/public_share
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/fstab; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Вт 2017-12-19 22:15:05 MSK; 16min ago
    Where: /media/public_share
     What: //localhost/public_share
     Docs: man:fstab(5)
           man:systemd-fstab-generator(8)
  Process: 1461 ExecMount=/bin/mount //localhost/public_share /media/public_share -t cifs -o guest,noperm (code=exited, status=32)

дек 19 22:15:05 hostname systemd[1]: Mounting /media/public_share...
дек 19 22:15:05 hostname mount[1461]: Unable to find suitable address.
дек 19 22:15:05 hostname systemd[1]: media-public_share.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited status=32
дек 19 22:15:05 hostname systemd[1]: Failed to mount /media/public_share.
дек 19 22:15:05 hostname systemd[1]: media-public_share.mount: Unit entered failed state.
```

Changing address to 127.0.0.1, or setting 127.0.0.1 with options `username=guest,password=,noperm` do not remove "Unable to find suitable address" message.

I moved **update 2** and **update 3** to answer.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @Rinzwind. See updates above. It does not work. Do you have other suggestions?

Comment: 3rd attempt :D have you seen this page: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently ? maybe one if those works :)

Comment: 3rd attempt does not help. I added and tested quick dirty hack with `/etc/network/if-up.d`. It just works.

Comment: Adding `x-systemd.automount,noauto` to */etc/fstab* helps without hacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem may be solved with one of the following solutions:

- Quick dirty hack with `/etc/network/if-up.d`:

  ```
  cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/network/if-up.d/zz-mount-all
  #!/bin/sh
  mount -a

  EOF

  sudo chmod a+x /etc/network/if-up.d/zz-mount-all
  ```

With this change it mounts normally:

```
$ systemctl status media-public_share.mount 
● media-public_share.mount - /media/public_share
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/fstab; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (mounted) (Result: exit-code) since Вт 2017-12-19 23:17:34 MSK; 7s ago
    Where: /media/public_share
     What: //127.0.0.1/public_share
     Docs: man:fstab(5)
           man:systemd-fstab-generator(8)
  Process: 1481 ExecMount=/bin/mount //127.0.0.1/public_share /media/public_share -t cifs -o guest,noperm (code=exited, status=32)
```

It works even with localhost address.

- It works as expected without hacks if I add `x-systemd.automount,noauto` to */etc/fstab* as

  ```
   //localhost/public_share /media/public_share/ cifs guest,noperm,x-systemd.automount,noauto 0 255
  ```

and it creates two systemd units:

```
$ systemctl status media-public_share.*
● media-public_share.mount - /media/public_share
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/fstab; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (mounted) since Ср 2017-12-20 20:33:10 MSK; 3min 4s ago
    Where: /media/public_share
     What: //localhost/public_share
     Docs: man:fstab(5)
           man:systemd-fstab-generator(8)
  Process: 2461 ExecMount=/bin/mount //localhost/public_share /media/public_share -t cifs -o guest,noperm,x-systemd.automount (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

дек 20 20:33:10 hostname systemd[1]: Mounting /media/public_share...
дек 20 20:33:10 hostname systemd[1]: Mounted /media/public_share.

● media-public_share.automount
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/fstab; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Ср 2017-12-20 20:33:02 MSK; 3min 12s ago
    Where: /media/public_share
     Docs: man:fstab(5)
           man:systemd-fstab-generator(8)

дек 20 20:33:09 hostname systemd[1]: media-public_share.automount: Got automount request for /media/public_share, triggered by 2456 (pool)
Warning: Journal has been rotated since unit was started. Log output is incomplete or unavail
```

But this solution adds two share icons to my Caja file-manager window.

So I'll use `if-up.d` hack.